# css issue for different mobile

Tags: css, responsive

i am using this css to show some fixed part in mobile screen down part.
but in Samson grand prime its work good but in Samsung j7 max it's little small in width.let me give you code and pic

```
      .footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #b1b1b1;
    height:65px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 3px 0px rgba(133,133,133,1);

    z-index:10000;
} 
.kafyfooter{
 display:block !important;   
 z-index:10000;
}

.footermenu {
    width:7%;
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    padding:22px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(204,204,204,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(204,204,204,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(204,204,204,1);

}
```

**: Samsung grand prime picture :**
https://gyazo.com/9eaf2240c5d0f91a4d57c3a787598e4f

**: Samsung J7 Max picture :**
https://gyazo.com/2c48dc559c3a5e9948fc0c6b11a8ae71

Answer (score 0):

`width: 7%;` seems to be too little (and the menu item gets stretched to fit its contents which might depend on screen resolution).

Either set width correctly or use a grid for your footer. (**edit**: I mean, use `display: grid;` on your footer)

Also, to make it look even more "same" on different devices, consider using units like vh, vw, rem and so on ( https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp ), because px can be everything from *reeeeaaally tiny* to *clearly visible as blocks* depending on screen.

Comment: this width you talking about is for this place https://gyazo.com/28e8e835acb402643d744ba4149fa10f

Comment: Ah I see, I wrongly assumed you had `box-sizing: border-box;` set. Set this and increase width to about 20% then it should already be better. But the cleanest solution would imho still be using a grid with all the columns set to 1fr width